# Why can't I use static members inside class in c++?

Tags: c++, static

```
using namespace std;
class test{
    private:
    int a,b;
    public:
    static int count=0;
    test(int a=10,int b=10){
        count++;
    }
};
int main(){
    test t;
    cout<<t.count<<endl;
    test t1;
    cout<<t1.count<<endl;

}
```

I have used static member which is initialized inside the class, I have tried outside the class it works fine, but I don't get how is that a error in first place which is initializing the member inside class.

When I run the above code it gives me the following error:
**ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'test::count'.**

Why I cant initialize a static member inside class?

Comment: Isn't the error message clear enough? Just initialise it outside the class. The reason is probably to be consistent with the way that global variables are declared and defined. You initialise a global variable at it's definition not at it's declaration.

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). There are plenty of dupes for this. The first step is to do "search and then research" as explained in [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Moreover, this is explained in any beginner level C++ book.

Answer (score 4):

The error is quite clear, you can't initialize the variables when you declare them.

Instead declare them like normal (without initialization) and then remember to add their *definitions* outside of the class, with the actual initialization:

```
class test{
    private:
    int a,b;
    public:
    static int count;
    test(int a=10,int b=10){
        count++;
    }
};
int test::count=0;
```

From the C++17 standard inline definition and initialization of static member variables was added:

```
class test{
    private:
    int a,b;
    public:
    inline static int count=0;  // Note the inline keyword
    test(int a=10,int b=10){
        count++;
    }
};
```